# hook_user_insert() vs hook_user()

Tags: hooks, users

can someone please explain the difference between

hook_user_insert() and

hook_user() with $op='insert'

i mean is hook_user with $op='$edit' is invoked after a user create an account??

cos i am trying to get some custom field values when a user create a new account.
i used this code for testing:

```
function myModule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'insert' ){
    dpm($edit)
  }
}
```

and it don't return nothing after creating a new user account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that [`hook_user`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_user/6) is for Drupal 6 and [`hook_user_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) is for Drupal 7.

Most (all?) of the API functions in Drupal 6 and earlier that accepted an `$op` parameter got split out into individual functions in Drupal 7.  This happened with `hook_block`, `hook_nodeapi`, and some others.

For Drupal 7, the full set of user hooks is described at [user.api.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/7).